# Failed to auto initialize the Facebook SDK error ,with firebase auth

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

Im getting this error on production (Works fine in developement), in my react Native Expo project with FireBase auth (plus redux toolkit in Windows with VsCode if this is a relevent info)

```
Failed to auto initialize the Facebook SDK
A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
```

My problem is that Im only using Google singin and email+password, i had facebookauth for tries but then removed it and removed anything that mentions it in the entire code.

Any idea why this error subsists? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

add Facebook app id and client token in your AndroidManifest.xml like that:

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/><!--add app id-->
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/><!--client token-->
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

or you can also initialize it in your App.tsx file like that:

```
import {Settings} from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';
useEffect(() => {
    Settings.setAppID(Config.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
    Settings.initializeSDK();
    
  }, []);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is an expo project it deosnt have a manifest.xml file, also i dont want facebook auth in the project at all, i actually want to get rid of it